# Lifting $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triples

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, characteristic-p

Let

- $k$ be an algebraically closed field,
- $G$ a (smooth, connected) reductive algebraic group over $k$,
- $H$ a (smooth, connected) reductive group of semisimple rank 1, and
- $T$ a maximal torus in $H$.

I am specifically interested in the case where the characteristic of $k$ is a bad prime for $G$.

Suppose that we are given a group embedding $F_T : T \to G$ and a $T$-equivariant Lie-algebra embedding $f_H : \mathfrak h \to \mathfrak g$, such that the restrictions to $\mathfrak t$ of $f_H$ and the derivative of $F_T$ agree.  Can we extend $F_T$ to an embedding $H \to G$ whose derivative is $f_H$?

(I know that most results in this area are stated under the assumption of good characteristic, or even of characteristic 0, but I don't actually know any of the counterexamples or where to look for them, so I can't tell if the hypothesis of the existence of $T$ is strong enough to allow me to overcome bad characteristic.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically not, even for good characteristic. This comes up indirectly in my paper with Adam Thomas [The Jacobson–Morozov theorem and complete reducibility of Lie subalgebras, JLMS](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms.12067) [arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.06234).

The nilpotent orbits of $G$ on $\mathfrak g$ in characteristic $0$ have representatives $e_{\mathbb Z}$ which are sums of root elements and which remain in distinct orbits when base-changed to a field of good characteristic. Furthermore, each can be completed to an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple $(e_{\mathbb Z},h_{\mathbb Z},f_{\mathbb Z})\in\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb Z}^3$—this is a result of Pommerening, though Thomas and I extend it slightly. Denote by $(e,h,f)$ the elements $(e\otimes 1,h\otimes 1,f\otimes 1)$ of $(\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb Z}\otimes k)^3$. We have $h$ is toral, so $\mathfrak t=\langle h\rangle$ is a torus of $\mathfrak{g}$. Since $h$ can be expressed as an integral combination of coroots, $\mathfrak t$ can be lifted to a torus $T$ such that $T$ normalises $\langle e\rangle$ and $\langle f\rangle$. Let $\mathfrak{h}=\langle e,h,f\rangle\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2$. We have that $T$ normalises $\mathfrak{h}$, so that the embedding $\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}$ is $T$ equivariant. Suppose we could lift this to $F_H:H\to G$ for some reductive $H$. (So $H\cong \operatorname{SL}_2$ or $\operatorname{PGL}_2$.)

Take the case that $e$ is a regular nilpotent element of $\mathfrak g$. Then a non-trivial unipotent element of $H$ must be regular too. But for $p$ less than the Coxeter number of $G$, a regular unipotent element has order at least $p^2$, so cannot be embedded into an $SL_2$ or $PGL_2$ (whose unipotents have order $p$).

EDITED: I initially expected this problem goes away if you insist $p$ is bigger than the Coxeter number of $G$, *because* I said there is a 1-1 correspondence between conjugacy classes of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$ and subgroups of $G$ of type $A_1$. This is obviously wrong however, since in positive characteristic one gets many more irreducible representations for $SL_2$ than for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, giving many more $SL_2$ or $PGL_2$ subgroups of $GL_n$ than $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ subalgebras, c.f. Steinberg's tensor product theorem.

By way of correction, if $p$ is bigger than the Coxeter number, all unipotent elements have order $p$. Then one can cite Theorem 4.2 of
*Lawther, R.; Testerman, D. M.*, [**(A_1) subgroups of exceptional algebraic groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/memo/0674), Mem. Am. Math. Soc. 674, 131 p. (1999). [ZBL0936.20039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0936.20039). in which an $A_1$ subgroup is guaranteed such that the Lie algebra of its root group contains nilpotent elements of the same Bala–Carter type; *a fortiori* one that corresponds under a Springer isomorphism.

Comment: It seems that at some point you switch from characteristic $0$ to characteristic $p$, but I guess characteristic $0$ was just motivation.  Do you have a reference for the fact that about regular unipotent elements when $p$ is less than the Coxeter number?

Comment: One reference is [Liebeck-Seitz, Unipotent and Nilpotent Classes in Simple Algebraic Groups and Lie Algebras] and look in the index for 'Orders …'. This probably goes back to the Order Formula 0.4 in [Testerman, A_1-type overgroups of elements of order p]. (Will clarify where I base-change to char p.)

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting answer, and the pointer to your paper!

Comment: If $e$ is a regular nilpotent element, why does it follow that unipotent elements of $H$ are regular unipotent?

Comment: @spin. There must be a better way to do this, maybe using a Springer isomorphism and/or associated cocharacters, but here is an answer that I think works. Let $U$ be the unipotent radical of a Borel of $H$. By the Borel–Tits theorem, we can conjugate $U$ into the unipotent radical of a Borel of $G$. Since $e$ is regular, it must be supported on all the simple roots. Since $Lie(U)=\langle e\rangle$, the same must be true of $1\neq u\in U$. Hence $u$ is a regular unipotent of $U$.

Comment: An argument that avoids the Springer isomorphism and associated cocharacters is certainly good, since those are both comparatively large-$p$ phenomena, and here we're interested in the small-$p$ case.  (I was suspicious of "the same must be true", but it's just saying that, since the derivative at the identity of $U \to U_\alpha$ is non-trivial, so is $U \to U_\alpha$ itself, and that's perfectly reasonable.  ($U \to U_\alpha$ comes from $U \subseteq R := \operatorname{Rad}_u(B) \to R/[R, R] \cong \prod U_\alpha$, product possibly including some non-simple roots for small $p$.))

Comment: I'm not sure what the Borel–Tits theorem is (maybe just the statement that *any* connected unipotent subgroup can be so conjugated?), but conjugacy of $U$ into the unipotent radical of a Borel is elementary:  the chosen Borel of $H$ is a connected soluble subgroup of $H$, hence of $G$, hence is contained in a maximal connected soluble subgroup $B$ of $G$, which is a Borel; and, since it is unipotent, it has trivial projection on the torus $B/\operatorname{Rad}_u(B)$, so is contained in $\operatorname{Rad}_u(B)$.

Comment: @LSpice. Agreed, that's reasonable. The B-T thm says that any closed subgroup $H$ of reductive $G$ lives in a parabolic $P$ of $G$ such that $R_u(H)\subseteq R_u(P)$.